# Multiplying masked arrays changes fill value in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 masked arrays, both of the form:

```
masked_array(data =
 [[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 ..., 
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]],
             mask =
 [[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 ..., 
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]],
       fill_value = -9999.0)
```

When I multiply them, the fill_value changes to `fill_value = 1e+20`

Why is that happening? and how can I retain the previous fill value? This is how i am multpliying them:

```
array_a * array_b
```

Comment: Are you sure both have the same fill_value?  In my quick tests it looks like the result gets the fill_value from the first argument.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, just double checked, both have the same fill_value i.e. -9999.0

Comment: I can reproduce this: `x = np.random.randn(10, 10); m = np.ma.masked_array(x, x < 0.5, fill_value=1); (m * m).fill_value == 1e20`. This occurs regardless of the fill value, but not when using `np.multiply(m, m)` rather than the `*` operator.

Comment: This could be a regression - I see it in numpy 1.10.4, but not numpy 1.8.2. In fact, the same behavior occurs with `+`, `-`, `/` etc., but not with `np.add`, `np.subtract`, `np.divide` etc.

Comment: cool @ali_m, sounds like a numpy bug? I am using numpy version 1.10.4

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was introduced in this commit: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/3c6b6baba587297633b8744a3b2ade8644ad8a5e which is present from v1.10.0 onwards. I'm not 100% sure whether it should be considered a bug. Here is a related open issue: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3762

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18879272/1461210

Comment: thanks @ali_m, i would be happy to accept an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you're referring to was introduced by [this commit](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/3c6b6baba587297633b8744a3b2ade8644ad8a5e) from October 2013, which found its way into releases from v1.10.0 onwards.

I'm not 100% sure whether or not it should be considered a bug. It seems unreasonable to me, but the documentation doesn't seem to specify what *should* happen to the fill value when a ufunc is applied to it. There are a [couple](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3762) of related [open issues](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7122) on the numpy GitHub tracker.